# Is the physics of $j = \rho v$ questionable? What are the consequences?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, electric-current, thermal-radiation

In electrodynamics you have the quantity $\mathbf{j}$, which represents density of current per surface area. It is often said that $\mathbf{j} = \rho\mathbf{v}$, for geometric reasons.

When I make the parallel with the energy per surface area $I \leftrightarrow \mathbf{j}$ radiated by a black body with energy density $\mathcal{E} \leftrightarrow \rho$, I note, however, that $I = \frac{c}{4} \mathcal{E}$ (there is an additional factor of $1/4$).

The difference is that in the case of a black body there is no fixed direction for the propagation of energy, rather it is propagated in all directions equally and I need to take only the light propagated outside of the black body.

The black body can be seen as a place where $<\mathbf{v}>$, intended as the average velocity of propagated energy, is zero. And we still see that energy is being propagated outside of the body. In a sense, $j^2$ is not zero.

Returning to electrodynamics, it seems that $\mathbf{j} = \rho \mathbf{v}$ does not suffice to describe the propagation of charge when the charges do not follow a simple motion. Maybe the situation is better treated in the framework of hydrodynamics, but has this consequences for the formulation of other equations, such as continuity equation?

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect a direct correspondence between $I$ and $\vec j$, or rather, between $\mathcal{E}$ and $\rho$, since the $\rho$ is the *charge density*, not an *energy density*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I actually fail to see the reason for them to be different. Perhaps you can help?

Comment: One is Joules per volume, the other Coulomb per volume? If you think they correspond, whats the dimensionful conversion factor?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It would be the same thing to say that $1/2I\omega^2$ and $1/2 m v^2$ are conceptually different because of the units

Comment: That's still not a real argument - if you think that **EM** is inconsistent/wrong with $\vec j = \rho \vec v$, then you have to show an **EM** phenomenon where that formula is wrong. Analogies are nice, but they're never precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the equation $\mathbf{j} = \mathbf{v}\rho$, $\mathbf{v}$ is the average velocity of charges and the equation describes the *net* flow of charge.

A black body spectrum describes a system at thermodynamic equilibrium and at thermodynamic equilibrium there is, by definition, not net transfer of heat. This means that the net energy flux through a surface is always $0$. For many applications we are interested in the average *total* flux in a particular direction and this is given by the result $I = \frac{c}{4}\varepsilon$. The equivalent result for a collection of massive particles would be given the rate of [effusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effusion). If instead of a thermal distribution you had, say, a beam of light the intensity would be given by $I = c\varepsilon$.